# How to generate graphml from report with jqassistant, asciidoc and maven

Tags: maven, asciidoc, graphml, jqassistant

I am using jqassistant 1.2.0 with asciidoc 1.5.3 - all in maven. 
My question is a specific question for the maven plugin "jqassistant". I am scanning a large java war from a server using "mvn clean install" as the default command line prompt.

I am having trouble generating a graphml file with jqassistant. It should work without having to specifiy graphml as a plugin (as it is loaded by default in version 1.2.0 of jqassistant). Executing the analysis gives me the generated html files... but no graphml file. I have specified a folder for the graphml which remains empty. Leaving the specified folder out doesn't change anything. The documentation suggest that all you need to do in order for graphmls to be generated is: 
- write a concept whichs name ends in ".graphml"
- write the return in such a way:

RETURN

{

role : "graph",

parent : something,

nodes : collect([collectednodetype1, collectednodetype2]),

relationships : collect([relationship1,relationship2])

} as NameOfPicture

i have done this and i don't get any errors... however i also don't get the picture. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencies of the plugin were missing